# How is a TypedData value validated?

Tags: 8

I do not understand how the Boolean (just for example) is validated. This is my code:

```
$tdm = \Drupal::typedData();
$data = $tdm->create(array('type' => 'boolean'), 1000);
drush_print_r($data->validate());
```

The `$data->validate()` returns a list of ConstraintViolations, but where is the logic of these constraints, per `Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\Boolean` does not implements `getConstraints` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive types are special case.

By default, they get the PrimitiveType validation constraint in TypedDataManager::getConstraints().

```
<?php
// Auto-generate a constraint for data types implementing a primitive
// interface.
if (is_subclass_of($type_definition['class'], '\Drupal\Core\TypedData\PrimitiveInterface')) {
  $constraints[] = $validation_manager->create('PrimitiveType', array());
}
?>
```

Validation constraints are usually provided in one of the following places:

- The plugin annotation (see e.g. EntityReferenceItem)
- base field/property definitions (see e.g. Node::baseFieldDefinitions(), title field)
- By overriding the getConstraints() method on a typed data class.